# Bluetooth not working properly

Tags: bluetooth

At first it worked then it stopped working. After searching for some solutions I found out that reinstalling Bluetooth module would fix it.

```
sudo rmmod btusb; sudo modprobe btusb
```

But it didn't work and now I'm not able to activate Bluetooth at all.

Comment: Even after restart?

Comment: Hello Pierre! Ive been trying things to make it work, and idk what happened but now i can turn it on again. Im new to ubuntu and i think its great but bluetooth sucks so much with it! Im scared to touch bluetooth agian.

Comment: 20.04? Add the output of `hcitool dev`